# Can't see image that was uploaded

Tags: linux, image-uploading, raspbian

I have moved my xampp server to raspbian for image uploading. I can access the server, folder via browser and can see that image was registered in DB but unfortunately there is no image at that folder.

If you need more specific information let me know.

My phone app: https://gist.github.com/DoIReallyNeedIt/a068c69958f269ad1d1a373d9ec8bcdb
Connection to server:

```
<?php

$user_name = "root";
$user_pass = "root";
$host_name = "localhost";
$db_name = "mydb";

$con = mysqli_connect ($host_name, $user_name, $user_pass, $db_name);


if ($con)

{

$image = $_POST["image"];
$name =date('Y').date('m').date('d'). "_" . date('H'). date('i'). "_". $_POST["name2"]."_".$_POST["name1"];
$sql = "insert into imageinfo(name) values ('$name')";
$upload_path = "uploads/$name.jpg";


if(mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
    file_put_contents ($upload_path, base64_decode($image));
    echo json_encode (array ('response'=>'Nuotrauka buvo sėkmingai įkelta'));

}

else {
    echo json_encode (array ('response'=>'Nuotraukos įkelti nepayvko'));
}
}
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem. For some reason chmod didn't saved for folders